# How to generate two Unique ID in SQL Server start from different region with some criteria?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I wants to generate two unique ID, with different region,

For example:

I have a radio button to choose either one of country `America` or `Australia`.

- If user chooses `America`, the unique ID should start from `1111` and keep going like `1112,1113,1114`
- If they choose `Australia`, the unique ID should start from `5555` and when user selecting next time, it should be `5556,5557`

In my database, there will be one column called `Region`, that will hold this number

Thanks

Comment: You will need a trigger to implement this functionality.  It is usually better to just have an id column and to encode the location separately.

Comment: @GordonLinoff give me example please.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to implement what you are asking by creating this table with CountryID as the primary key that increments by 1

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
 [CountryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Country] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [Region] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [CountryID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Then I created this trigger.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[setRegion] 
ON  [dbo].[Table_1] 
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @CountryID int = (SELECT CountryID FROM inserted);
DECLARE @Country varchar(50) = (SELECT Country FROM inserted);
DECLARE @Region int = (SELECT MAX (Region)
                        FROM Table_1
                        WHERE Country = @Country);

IF @Region IS NULL
BEGIN
    IF @Country = 'America'
    BEGIN
        SET @Region = 1111;
    END
    IF @Country = 'Australia'
    BEGIN
        SET @Region = 5555;
    END
END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Region = @Region + 1;
    END

UPDATE Table_1
SET Region = @Region
WHERE CountryID = @CountryID

END
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_1] ENABLE TRIGGER [setRegion]
GO
```

I tested it with this insert script

```
INSERT INTO Table_1 (Country) VALUES('America') 
INSERT INTO Table_1 (Country) VALUES('America') 
INSERT INTO Table_1 (Country) VALUES('America') 
INSERT INTO Table_1 (Country) VALUES('America') 
INSERT INTO Table_1 (Country) VALUES('America')
INSERT INTO Table_1 (Country) VALUES('Australia') 
INSERT INTO Table_1 (Country) VALUES('Australia')
INSERT INTO Table_1 (Country) VALUES('Australia')
INSERT INTO Table_1 (Country) VALUES('Australia')
INSERT INTO Table_1 (Country) VALUES('Australia')
INSERT INTO Table_1 (Country) VALUES('Australia')
GO

SELECT *
FROM Table_1
ORDER BY Country,Region
```

Comment: your result is wrong. But I got some idea, thanks, it's inserting in sequence order from 1

Comment: If you want an aggregated table Id, I would store that in a separate column and leave the real Id column alone.